# Shell script variable replacing characters

Tags: shell, variables, string

I have a variable var="abcde$$$$$$$$fff$$gg". I want to replace all $ with space ' ' but the following puts just one space

```
var=$( echo "$var" | tr '$' ' ')
```

How can i replace them all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Works for me. You'll need to use single quotes or escape the dollar signs, otherwise they are removed from the double-quoted string:

```
echo 'abcde$$$$$$$$fff$$gg' | tr '$' ' '
abcde        fff  gg

echo "abcde\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$fff\$\$gg" | tr '$' ' '
abcde        fff  gg

echo abcde\$\$\$\$\$\$\$\$fff\$\$gg | tr '$' ' '
abcde        fff  gg

echo $'abcde$$$$$$$$fff$$gg' | tr '$' ' '
abcde        fff  gg
```

Answer (score 22):

you can replace without calling external commands (using bash)

```
$ var='abcde$$$$$$$$fff$$gg'
$ echo "${var//$/ }"
abcde        fff  gg
```

Note that you should use single quotes so that the "$" sign does not get interpolated

Comment: I read value from a file into var. So is it like var=' ' or var=" " ?

Comment: if you have read the value from file, then `var=''` or `var=""` is irrelevant. the variable that you used when you read the line from the file would just be like `var`. So just do `echo "${whatever_variable_you_used//$/}"`

Answer (score 8):

Old question, but I  write this for them hwo will come here after a search with their diseired  search engine You have to use `echo -e` like this

```
var="$( echo -e "$var" | tr  '$' ' '  )"
```