# GITHUB ACTIONS replace character in string

Tags: replace, github-actions

I'm trying to replace a character in a variable within a GITHUB actions step

```
  - name: Set Up DB Name
    run: |
      DB_NAME="${GITHUB_REF_SLUG/-/_}"
      echo $DB_NAME
```

I'm getting a bad request error

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I successfully made the character replace works (with `GITHUB_REPOSITORY`) using this implementation:

```
job1:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: character-replacement-test
      run: |
        REPO=$GITHUB_REPOSITORY
        DB_NAME="${REPO//-/_}"
        echo $DB_NAME
```

I couldn't get to the same result with 2 lines.
*(But someone more experienced with bash might help us get there as well).*

**Evidence:**

[image: evidence]

So in your case, it should work using this code if you substitute the `GITHUB_REPOSITORY` by `GITHUB_REF_SLUG` in your workflow.

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833086/shell-script-variable-replacing-characters) as reference.

Comment: No joy, I got this error: /__w/_temp/c7a0ceca-3028-4b97-a36c-3ef2f667dda3.sh: 2: /__w/_temp/c7a0ceca-3028-4b97-a36c-3ef2f667dda3.sh: Bad substitution
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

Comment: Could you please add the whole workflow to your question to see if there is something different that might be impacting what we are trying to do?

Comment: One-liner: `run: echo "CACHE_KEY=${GITHUB_REF////_}" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

Comment: Shocked that `replace` isn't a supported [Github Actions Expression](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions).